# How to offset overlapped Font Awesome icons?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Is there a way to overlap two Font Awesome icons in such a way that it looks like the [`files`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/files-o/) icon with respect to the [`file`](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/file-o/) icon? I don't want to stack the icons but rather have one cover like 50% of another. Thanks!

Comment: well initially you can use position property on icons but its will be great if you share some code u tried..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not just use CSS padding to offset one of the icons?

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-file fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-file fa-stack-2x" style="padding-left:15px;padding-top:15px;"></i>
</span>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/sx7fk582/

Comment: then whats wrong with this icon `fa-files-o`. http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/files-o/

Comment: I think OP was just using the files icon as an example. Presumably, he wants to overlap two different icons.

Comment: @Matthew Exactly. Thanks a bunch for the quick respose! I forgot that you can add padding to inline elements.